# Assigning values from a row of a table to a popup form in the same row

Tags: javascript, jsp, controller, bootstrap-modal

I have implemented the following table in my JSP.

**JSP**

```
<table  id="credStoreTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Product Id</th>
            <th>Credential Key</th>
            <th>Created By</th>
            <th>Created Date</th>
            <th>Updated By</th>
            <th>Updated Date</th>
            <th>Copied From</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <c:forEach items="${credentials}" var="cred">
            <tr>
                <td>${cred.productId}</td>
                <td>${cred.credentialKey}</td>
                <td>${cred.audit.createdBy}</td>
                <td>${cred.audit.createdDate}</td>
                <td>${cred.audit.updatedBy}</td>
                <td>${cred.audit.updatedDate}</td>
                <td>${cred.audit.copiedFrom}</td>
                <td>
                <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2" >Delete</button>

                  <!-- Modal -->
                  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" role="dialog">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">

                      <!-- Modal content-->
                      <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                          <h4 class="modal-title">Update Information</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                          <form method="post" action="${cred.productId}/${cred.credentialKey}/delete">
                            Product Id: ${cred.productId}
                            <br>
                            Current Key: ${cred.credentialKey}
                            <br>
                            Are you sure you want to delete?
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="add"></label>
                            <input id="add" type="submit" name="add" class="btn btn-primary" value="Ok"/>
                          </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                      </div> 
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Modify</button>

                  <!-- Modal -->
                  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">

                      <!-- Modal content-->
                      <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                          <h4 class="modal-title">Update Information</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                          <form method="post" action="${cred.productId}/${cred.credentialKey}/modify">
                            Product Id: ${cred.productId}
                            <br>
                            Current Key: ${cred.credentialKey}
                            <br>
                            Enter New Key: 
                            <input type="text" name="key" id="key" placeholder="Key">
                            <br>
                            Enter New Password: 
                            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
                            <br><br>
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="add"></label>
                            <input id="add" type="submit" name="add" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit"/>
                          </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                      </div> 
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1">Copy</button>

                  <!-- Modal -->
                  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" role="dialog">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">

                      <!-- Modal content-->
                      <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                          <h4 class="modal-title">Copy Information</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                          <form method="post" action="${cred.productId}/${cred.credentialKey}/copy">
                            Current Product Id: ${cred.productId}
                            <br>
                            Current Key: ${cred.credentialKey}
                            <br>
                            Enter New Product Suite: 
                            <input type="text" name="productsuite" id="productsuite" placeholder="Product-Suite">
                            <br>
                            Enter New Product: 
                            <input type="text" name="product" id="product" placeholder="Product">
                            <br>
                            Enter New Key: 
                            <input type="text" name="key" id="key" placeholder="Key">
                            <br><br>
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="add"></label>
                            <input id="add" type="submit" name="add" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit"/>
                          </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                      </div> 
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                </td> 
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

As you can see, in my table I have created 8 columns. The last column is "Actions". Here I can delete, modify or copy the information belonging to that row. I have used bootstrap popup feature to complete these actions. But the problem is, whenever I try to delete, modify or copy a row, it always perform these actions for the last updated or added row (Not the row I want it to). How can I make sure it performs these actions for the row I want?
my controller code for these actions are given below, although I'm sure they're not the problem.

```
@RequestMapping(value="{productId}/{credentialKey}/modify", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView getProductDetailsView(@PathVariable String productId,
        @PathVariable String credentialKey,
        @ModelAttribute("key") String newCredentialKey,
        @ModelAttribute("password") String newCredential,
        @ModelAttribute("dirId") String dirId, 
        RedirectAttributes attributes){

    Credential cred = new Credential();
    cred.setProductId(productId);
    cred.setCredentialKey(credentialKey);
    boolean saveSuccess = awsCredStoreService.updateCredential(cred, newCredentialKey, newCredential, "dev", dirId);
    if(saveSuccess){
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/?saveSuccess=true");
    }
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/?saveSuccess=false");
}

@RequestMapping(value="{productId}/{credentialKey}/delete", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView deleteCredential(RedirectAttributes attributes,
        @PathVariable String productId,
        @PathVariable String credentialKey){
    boolean saveSuccess = awsCredStoreService.deleteCredential(productId, credentialKey, "dev");
    if(saveSuccess){
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/?saveSuccess=true");
    }
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/?saveSuccess=false");
}

@RequestMapping(value="{productId}/{credentialKey}/copy", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView copyCredential(RedirectAttributes attributes,
        @PathVariable String productId,
        @PathVariable String credentialKey,
        @ModelAttribute("productsuite") String productsuite,
        @ModelAttribute("product") String product,
        @ModelAttribute("key") String key,
        @ModelAttribute("dirId") String dirId){
    Audit audit = new Audit();
    Date date = new Date();
    Credential currentCred = new Credential();
    Credential copyCred = new Credential();
    audit.setCreatedBy(dirId);
    audit.setCreatedDate(date.toString());
    audit.setCopiedFrom(productId+"-"+credentialKey);
    currentCred.setProductId(productId);
    currentCred.setCredentialKey(credentialKey);
    copyCred.setProductId(productsuite+"-"+product);
    copyCred.setCredentialKey(key);
    copyCred.setAudit(audit);
    boolean saveSuccess = awsCredStoreService.copyCredential(currentCred, copyCred, "dev");
    if(saveSuccess){
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/?saveSuccess=true");
    }
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/?saveSuccess=false");
}
```

I am very new to using JSP, HTML, JS and CSS. Any kind of help would be really great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating modal dialogs as much as rows with the same Id.
You can set different Ids(using productId)

```
<table  id="credStoreTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Product Id</th>
            <th>Credential Key</th>
            <th>Created By</th>
            <th>Created Date</th>
            <th>Updated By</th>
            <th>Updated Date</th>
            <th>Copied From</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <c:forEach items="${credentials}" var="cred">
            <tr>
                <td>${cred.productId}</td>
                <td>${cred.credentialKey}</td>
                <td>${cred.audit.createdBy}</td>
                <td>${cred.audit.createdDate}</td>
                <td>${cred.audit.updatedBy}</td>
                <td>${cred.audit.updatedDate}</td>
                <td>${cred.audit.copiedFrom}</td>
                <td>
                <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalDelete${cred.productId}" >Delete</button>

                  <!-- Modal -->
                  <div class="modal fade" id="myModalDelete${cred.productId}" role="dialog">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">

                      <!-- Modal content-->
                      <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                          <h4 class="modal-title">Update Information</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                          <form method="post" action="${cred.productId}/${cred.credentialKey}/delete">
                            Product Id: ${cred.productId}
                            <br>
                            Current Key: ${cred.credentialKey}
                            <br>
                            Are you sure you want to delete?
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="add"></label>
                            <input id="add" type="submit" name="add" class="btn btn-primary" value="Ok"/>
                          </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                      </div> 
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalModify${cred.productId}">Modify</button>

                  <!-- Modal -->
                  <div class="modal fade" id="myModalModify${cred.productId}" role="dialog">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">

                      <!-- Modal content-->
                      <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                          <h4 class="modal-title">Update Information</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                          <form method="post" action="${cred.productId}/${cred.credentialKey}/modify">
                            Product Id: ${cred.productId}
                            <br>
                            Current Key: ${cred.credentialKey}
                            <br>
                            Enter New Key: 
                            <input type="text" name="key" id="key" placeholder="Key">
                            <br>
                            Enter New Password: 
                            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
                            <br><br>
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="add"></label>
                            <input id="add" type="submit" name="add" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit"/>
                          </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                      </div> 
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalCopy${cred.productId}">Copy</button>

                  <!-- Modal -->
                  <div class="modal fade" id="myModalCopy${cred.productId}" role="dialog">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">

                      <!-- Modal content-->
                      <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                          <h4 class="modal-title">Copy Information</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                          <form method="post" action="${cred.productId}/${cred.credentialKey}/copy">
                            Current Product Id: ${cred.productId}
                            <br>
                            Current Key: ${cred.credentialKey}
                            <br>
                            Enter New Product Suite: 
                            <input type="text" name="productsuite" id="productsuite" placeholder="Product-Suite">
                            <br>
                            Enter New Product: 
                            <input type="text" name="product" id="product" placeholder="Product">
                            <br>
                            Enter New Key: 
                            <input type="text" name="key" id="key" placeholder="Key">
                            <br><br>
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="add"></label>
                            <input id="add" type="submit" name="add" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit"/>
                          </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                      </div> 
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                </td> 
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

this will solve your problem but maybe not the efficient way cause you are creating a lot of modal dialogs(dom).

Comment: What you've posted worked on my machine. I'm guessing, I need to use script somehow to make it more efficient. Can you give me some guidance about how to make the code cleaner and more efficient?

Comment: you should create only 3 modals with different id(copy, modify, delete...) not at the end of your foreach, and call this modal from javascript functions, before showing modal you can set values on your form...